# using PHP variable in as filename in javascript / amchart

Tags: php, amcharts

Apologies if this is a silly question, but I am hoping someone might be able to help me. I am using **php** scripts to fetch **JSON** data to feed it into **amcharts** as part of a graphing system.

One thing i would like to do is to change the default filename, I have a code sample below that gives an idea of how to do that, but I am wondering how I can change the filename to a variable. I had tried to do things like $varFilename but i got unexpected char errors. I am guessing the answer is yes, but am I missing something and how can I make the "Your new file name without extension", a variable value?

```
 var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "fileName": "your new file name without extension", 
    // ...
  }
});
```

Apologies all, i stuffed up with my description. I do have a php script which is basically taking information from the database, formatting it as JSON and then presenting it to a HTML page. so within the HTML page I have a javascript function which is below;

```
<script>
     function qs(search_for) {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var parms = query.split('&');
        for (var i=0; i<parms.length; i++) {
            var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
            if (pos > 0  && search_for == parms[i].substring(0,pos)) {
                return parms[i].substring(pos+1);;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
</script>
```

I use this function to search for variables in the URL which are passed to the PHP script, what I want to do is get these variables and use them in the javascript;

```
'rh_chart.php?sensor=' + qs("sensor") + '&test_id=' + qs("test")
```

e.g. filename = qs(sensor) - qs(test)

Comment: PHP is a serverside language. It runs _before_ your website is loaded. Meaning you can't rely on a PHP variable inside a JS function that's being called _after_ the page is already loaded. You can either use a JS variable instead, or you'll have to use Ajax. Make PHP send the filename back through Ajax and save that inside a JS variable so you can use it.

Comment: if the name is known on the server (where PHP runs)  *before this page loads* not just on the client  and not fetched after the page loads then `"fileName": "<?=$varname ?>", ` should work, (this is the same as <?php echo $varname; ?>)

Comment: apologies, i had my description totally wrong :(

Comment: Going by your edit, what's stopping you from using `"fileName": qs("sensor") + qs("test")` in your page then? It should work if the page containing the chart has those query string variables.

Comment: Thanks, very strange because i tried that but it does not either change the filename, or error up for some reason :(.